# What is the practical purpose of a lens hood if any?

Tags: lens-hood

If a hood is to block unwanted light coming from the sides of the lens in use, because such light is detrimental to the picture taking, then hoods would be used at all times,because there almost always be light hitting the lens from all angles,  however hoods are not used that much.

Comment: "...however hoods are not used that much." I guess it depends who you hang out with. Mine are never off their lenses!

Answer (score 2):

The reduce or prevent lens flare from bright light sources at the edges of the lens.

It's not a bad idea to you use lens hood whenever possible as it will help prevent the lens from knocks.

I don't really agree with the statement that they aren't used that much because in fact they are used very broadly.